WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/wss/' failed in Django Channels
I'm trying to set up a WebSocket connection using Django Channels in my Django project. However, I keep encountering an error when trying to connect from the frontend JavaScript. The error message in the browser console is:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/wss/' failed

Here is my project structure:
project/
    ├── myproject/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   ├── asgi.py
    ├── myapp/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── consumers.py
    │   ├── routing.py
    │   ├── templates/
    │       ├── index.html
    ├── manage.py
    ├── passenger_wsgi.py
    ├── requirements.txt

My settings.py includes:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}

The asgi.py file is configured as follows:
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import myapp.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            myapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})

My routing.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('wss/', consumers.LoadConsumer.as_asgi()),
]

The consumer class in consumers.py:
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class LoadConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        pass

And here is the JavaScript code for the WebSocket connection:
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://example.com/wss/');

socket.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("WebSocket is open now.");
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("WebSocket message received:", event);
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
    console.log("Connection closed");
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log("WebSocket Error:", error);
};


Edit
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path('ws/', consumers.LoadConsumer.as_asgi()),
]


Which ASGI server are you using in this production environment?

Daphne I guess.

Can you confirm?

I can't as I'm in a host and I don't have access to terminal like they do in VPS to run or check commands.

Should I ask my provincer?

You have to be working with an ASGI server to be able to handle Websocket URLs.

I have good news! I successfully runned the daphne in my host but I still get the same error.

I don’t have your setup but I think this will help. Go through this and replicate the setup. I’m interested in the outcome. I hope it works.

I found it! Or at least I think I did. Starting in Django 2.0, path() was introduced as a simpler way to write URL paths in Django. Unfortunately this doesn’t provide everything Django Channels needs to provide routing. In their own words:

Note we use re_path() due to limitations in URLRouter.

I have no idea what limitations they encountered but it is plausible because even the Django team acknowledges that path() is a simpler interface while re_path() is for finer control and more versatility.
Most people actually make this mistake too so you are not alone in this. [1]
Change your code from using path() to using re_path() and you will be fine.

[1] Here [github] is one such case posited in the answer.

Tried it, Didn't worked

Try this: re_path(r"^wss/$", •••) because that is what you have in the Javascript of the OP. If it doesn’t work then we are looking at the wrong place.

Also tried that and didn't work (yeah that ws was my mistake i should've put wss but it didn't work anyways)

Add 'daphne' to the top of the INSTALLED_APPS setting, not 'channels'.
Tutorial: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html#integrate-the-channels-library
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'channels',
]

Also check whether you intended 'wss://example.com/wss/' (with your deployed domain) or 'wss://127.0.0.1:8000/wss/'.

Do you see Starting ASGI/Daphne version 3.0.2 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/when you runserver?

N‌o‌ ‌I‌ ‌d‌o‌n‌'‌t‌.

Actually I don't know where to see logs I only know how to see errors.

Are you running from terminal or deploying?

I'm running on cpanel.
